# Numerical integration of an ODE starting at a singular point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am interested in numerically integrating the ODE $$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{ay^2}{1-y^2}, \ \ \ a=const.$$ on the interval [1,b] (b>1) starting with the initial conditions x=1, y=1. I am aware that this ODE has an exact analytic solution, however I am not interested in this. If I try to use runge kutta I run into a problem since the right hand side is singular at the initial point. Is there a method for handling ODE's numerically when there is a singularity at the initial condition point?

Comment: I was thinking something like 0<a<1. I didn't think it should matter.

Comment: You could try looking at $\frac{dx}{dy}$.

Answer (score 1):

Yo are facing the following problems:

1. If $a>0$ there is no solution
2. If $a<0$ there are two solutions, one with $y(x)>1$ and the other with $y(x)<1$.

There is no way that Runge-Kutta can detect this.

Let $F(y)$ be the right hand side of the equation. A numerical method with step $h$ will try to use $F(1)$ to approximate $y(h)$; for instance, in Euler's method $y(h)\approx y(1)+h\,F(1)$. You can help the method providing the value of $y(h)$.

Alternatively, you can take as initial condition $y(1)=1\pm\epsilon$ with $\epsilon>0$ small, choosing the sign to select one of the two possible solutions. Of course this will work only if $a<0$.

Comment: I don't understand your comment on the values of a. If I integrate the equation and choose the integration constant to satisfy x=1 when y=1 I get x=-\frac{y^2+1}{ay}+(1+2/a). This result is independent of the value of a and I should be able to invert it to get y(x).

Comment: The solution is $$y(x)=\frac{2+a-a\,x\pm\sqrt{a(x-1)(a(x-1)-4)}}{2}.$$ If $a>0$, the term inside the square root is negative for $1<x<1+4/a$. If $a<0$ you get two solutions.

Answer (score 0):

A possibly valid approach is to pertube slightly your initial value (e.g. with a value slightly greater than your machine's epsilon), then run a fourth-order RK method with "small" stepsize. Normally, the solution you will obtain will be very close to the original.

Comment: I tried something of this sort ( although much greater than the machine epsilon ) and it seems not to have worked. The values I used were the conditions y=0.999 x=1.001 and a=1. The solution oscillates about the initial value ( this is not the behavior  when solved analytically ).